# Data interchange between two android apps in different device and different network?

Tags: android, android-studio, sockets, kotlin, server

Is it possible for two android apps to communicate and interchange data through Internet without need of any other server.

Eg :
One android app called "App A" and the other app called "App B"
[server app and a client app ].
"App A" and "App B" are in different devices and under different networks.
I want "App A" to send a message to "App B", and "App B" respond to that. I don't need any third-party server between the apps, just through the internet and using IP address.

I tried using the Ktor framework. But it only works under the same network.

```
implementation "io.ktor:ktor:1.2.5"
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:1.2.5"
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-gson:1.2.5"
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        embeddedServer(Netty, 8080) {
            install(ContentNegotiation) {
                gson {}
            }
            routing {
                get("/") {
                    call.respond(mapOf("message" to "Hello world"))
                }
            }
        }.start(wait = true)
    }
}
```

Comment: `just through internet and using ip address.` That is the whole point. Which ip do you have in mind? And please do not talk about apps a and b but over a server app and a client app as that is where all starts with.